# Importing sass files conditionally in to another sass file

Tags: sass

In a next.js project, I have a sass file called main.scss.
Here I'm importing another sass file with:

```
@import "style-1.scss";
```

But now I'm facing a situation where instead of style-1.scsss, I need to import another sass file called style-2.scss.

Basically I'm trying to find a way to import style-1.scss or style-2.scss conditionally based on a class in body or maybe based on existence of a prop.

Something like this:

```
if (body has class amp)
@import "style-2.scss";
esle
@import "style-1.scss";
```

Alternatively (although I don't think that I can use porps in a sass file)

```
if (prop two is true)
@import "style-2.scss";
esle
@import "style-1.scss";
```

The main idea is that only one of the two sass files should output any css and the other one shouldn't.
But I still couldn't find a working solution. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: SCSS is processed at *build time*. At that time no `body` or `document` exists. SCSS cannot help you with anything related to *run time*. You are going to have to resort to either context-based selectors in your files, or some Javascript shenanigans.

Comment: Do you have a separate build run for the AMP deliveries? If not: try to set one up. SASS supports a mechanism by which you can output different CSS depending on environment variables and `@if` directives. That is the way to go.